# No HTTP2 protocol between ngrok AWS server/client

Tags: ssl, server, client, http2, ngrok

I am trying to connect to my ngrok server on AWS EC2 instance with my ngrok client on windows via HTTP2, but whatever i've tried i always end up with http1.1 protocol.

I have generated a self-assigned SSL certificate both as also from an SSL certificate provider, but it didn't work. Both server and client are using the same certificate. Localhost connections are via HTTP2, but when i am trying to expose the local server with the ngrok server all my connection are with HTTP1.1, as also bad request, not secure connection, etc.

I followed this  [walkthrough]: https://www.svenbit.com/2014/09/run-ngrok-on-your-own-server/